# Convert array of indices to array of zeros where the index is one

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following numpy array representing indexes:

```
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3,
       3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
       4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
       5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5])
```

How can I convert this to an array of zeros where only the given index is a one?

Without numpy, this works:

```
a = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3,
       3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
       4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
       5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]

for i in range(len(a)):
    idx = a[i]
    a[i] = [0 for i in range(6)]
    a[i][idx] = 1

print(a)
```

```
>>> [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

However, I am looking for a numpy function (preferably no iterating).

Comment: The logic is unclear

Comment: I edited the question. Hopefully it's more clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your "index" array to index into the identity matrix:

```py
In [2]: indices = np.array([0, 0, 0, ...])  # provided by OP

In [3]: np.identity(6, int)[indices]
Out[3]:
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        .
        .
        .
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use [`np.identity`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.identity.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.identity(6, np.int64)
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use advanced indexing:

```
b = np.zeros((len(a), 6), dtype=a.dtype)
b[range(len(a)), a.tolist()] = 1
```

output:

```
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       ...
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       ...
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```